# Flex 3 DataGrid Column Width Problem

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, column-width

I'm pulling xml data to determine which columns are visible, and the widths of each column. My datagrid's width can change sinces its on one side of a HDividedBox. The visibility part works, but setting the width is causing headaches. Heres the code:

```
for(loop through column data retrieve from XML)
{ 
    newData[i] = dg.columns[Number(columnsOrder[i]) - 1];
    newData[i].visible = (Number(columnsVisibility[i]) == 1);
    newData[i].width = Number(columnsWidth[i]);
    trace(newData[i].headerText + " w:" + newData[i].width.toString() + " v:" + newData[i].visible.toString());
}
dg.columns = newData;
dg.invalidateList();
```

In the trace the width is correct for the first two items, however, its showing up as "20" for ever consecutive one...

```
Date w:240 v:true
Title w:184 v:true
Requestor w:20 v:true
Approved By w:20 v:true
Category w:20 v:false
Status w:20 v:false
Priority w:20 v:false
```

When I output Number(columnsWidth[i]) it shows up as the correct value so something weird is happening in the assignment of the width.

Been looking at this for a few hours now, and have tried multiple things to try to fix it to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > My datagrid's width can change sinces its on one side of a HDividedBox.

That's the problem right there.

I faced the exact same problem with Flex 2 and Flex 3 DataGridColumn width's whenever the width for the DataGrid was not fixed. The only solution I had was to fix the width of the DataGrid or switch to AdvancedDataGrid or other similar components.

Comment: I think this bug occurs if the DataGrid's size is too small to calculate the columns when it is created.

One work around is to set the width to something that will accommodate all the columns like 100, then in the creation complete event set the width to what you really want, such as percentWidth=100

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same thing in AdvancedDataGrid and it works.
Try by setting these values

```
  horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
  width="100%
```

and then add you columns this should work with HDividedBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this, it's what I believe is a bug in the DataGrid itself.

If you set minWidth="0" and horizontalScrollPolicy="{ScrollPolicy.AUTO}" on the DataGrid, you can then create DataGridColumn Objects with fixed widths and have it be obeyed properly.

However, there seems to still be an issue with the final column, when the DataGrid is still larger then the sum of all of the fixed widths, it will stretch the final DataGridColumn out.

You could get around this by adding a blank column at the end with no header text etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - we've run into this ourselves while building support for various column width modes. Just a little tidbit of information - if you want to set widths explicitly, make sure you do something like this:

```
var oldPolicy:String = grid.horizontalScrollPolicy;
grid.horizontalScrollPolicy ="on"
//set your widths here
grid.horizontalScrollPolicy =oldPolicy;
```