# fixed row width in DataGrid quirk

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid

I've got this issue:
I've got a dataGrid where whenever I set the column to not be resizable, the width gets messed up;

works:

```
var myCol:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Title");
myCol.width = 180;
```

doesn't work (width is about 40pixels):

```
var myCol:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("Title");
myCol.width = 180;
myCol.resizable = false;
```

has anyone come across this or know why this is happening?

I'm ready to just create my own dataGrid class now...

Comment: Can you post the rest of your `DataGrid` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that has helped us in the past : Before you set any width on a datagrid column, set the horizontalScrollPolicy to "on". You can set it back to "off" or "auto" after you set the width.

See this: [Flex 3 DataGrid Column Width Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302522/flex-3-datagrid-column-width-problem/6103088#6103088)

Comment: `horizontalScrollPolicy="on"`